# try rescue does not does not catch an error

Tags: elixir

```
  def page_request(url, proxy) do
    uri = URI.parse(proxy)
    case uri.host do
      nil -> raise "Host nil! #{proxy}"
      _ ->
        options =
        case uri.scheme do
            "socks5" -> default_params() ++ [proxy: {:socks5, String.to_charlist(uri.host), uri.port}]
            _-> default_params() ++ [proxy: String.to_charlist(proxy)]
        end
        try do #36 line!
          case HTTPoison.request(:get, String.to_charlist(url), "", [], options) do
            {:ok, response} ->
              %HTTPoison.Response{headers: header, body: body} = response
              gzipped = Enum.any?(header, fn (kv) ->
                case kv do
                  {"Content-Encoding", "gzip"} -> true
                  {"Content-Encoding", "x-gzip"} -> true
                  _ -> false
                end
              end)
              case body do
                nil -> {:ok, %{}}
                _ ->
                  if gzipped do
                    {:ok, :zlib.gunzip(body)}
                  else
                    {:ok, body}
                  end
              end
            {:error, reason} ->
              {:error, reason}
          end
        rescue
          error -> {:error, error}
        end
    end
  end
```

I can not understand why `try..rescue` does not catch an error?

```
15:34:24.537 [error] GenServer MyWeb.Worker1 terminating
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    (kernel) gen_tcp.erl:150: :gen_tcp.connect/4
    (hackney) /home/book/my_web/deps/hackney/src/hackney_connect.erl:247: :hackney_connect.do_connect/5
    (hackney) /home/book/my_web/deps/hackney/src/hackney.erl:354: :hackney.send_request/2
    (hackney) /home/book/my_web/deps/hackney/src/hackney.erl:810: :hackney.redirect/2
    (hackney) /home/book/my_web/deps/hackney/src/hackney.erl:742: :hackney.maybe_redirect1/3
    (hackney) /home/book/my_web/deps/hackney/src/hackney.erl:362: :hackney.send_request/2
    (httpoison) lib/httpoison/base.ex:439: HTTPoison.Base.request/9
    (my_web) lib/my_web.ex:37: MyWeb.page_request/2
Last message: :work
State: nil
```

I thought this code should catch any error

but in iex works:

Interactive Elixir (1.6.0) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

```
iex(1)> try do
...(1)> raise ArgumentError
...(1)> rescue
...(1)> error -> {:error, error}
...(1)> end
{:error, %ArgumentError{message: "argument error"}}
```

I looked through the [documentation](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/try-catch-and-rescue.html), but could not find the answer

elixir 1.6.1

example url http://google.com

```
  defp default_params(timeout \\ 25) do
      [ssl: [verify: :verify_none],
      timeout: timeout*1000,
      recv_timeout: timeout*1000,
      connect_timeout: timeout*1000,
      follow_redirect: true,
      hackney: [pool: false, insecure: true]]
  end
```

Comment: Can you give an example value for `url` and `options` which would make `HTTPoison.request` throw this error?

Comment: Also, can you try try/catch like this: `try do ... catch :exit, error -> error end`?

Comment: @Dogbert yes, `try..catch` works. I expanded the question

Comment: The values you gave don't raise any error for me..

Comment: @Dogbert perhaps this is due to the version of hackney. I use `{:hackney, "~> 1.8", override: true}`, `{:httpoison, "~> 1.0"}`. And I applied this pr https://github.com/benoitc/hackney/pull/469

Comment: @Marsel.V What are you trying to achieve with the `try-rescue` block? An argument error means you're not passing the right argument types to a function and it has to be fixed, not caught at runtime. As @bschaeffer mentioned, the error message says `15:34:24.537 [error] GenServer MyWeb.Worker1 terminating` which indicates that another process has terminated.

Answer (score 0):

To use `try rescue` here you should use `HTTPoison.request!`, which raises an error, not `HTTPoison.request`, which returns `{:ok, result}` or `{:error, error}`.

The clause `rescue` will not be triggered when `{:error, error}` tuple is returned, only when some `Error` is raised.

Comment: I do not understand. `HTTPoison` returns `{:error, error}` when it has itself handled the error. In my case, an `ArgumentError` error occurs, which is not caught by `HTTPoison`, and which rises higher. And there I try to catch it in `try..rescue`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `ArgumentError` is being raised in your block, but by `:hackney` in `MyWeb.WebWorker1` which is probably a separate process. You cannot rescue exceptions from a separate process.

Is `HTTPoison` async? I bet it still returns an error. If you added a `Logger` line to the `:error` case, I believe you'd see an error message there:

```
{:error, reason} ->
  Logger.debug(inspect(reason))
  {:error, reason}
```